# The benefit of declaring the capacity of an array as a variable of it's own in a class?

Tags: c++, class, conventions

I came across these codes and explanation about how we should create a class in C++.
The example class was about a bag, with an array for it to keep integers and a variable to count how many integers were in it :

```
class Bag {
public: 
  //...
private:
  int data[20];
  size_t count;
  //...
}
```

then it gave another code (the improved) :

```
class Bag {
public:
  static const size_t CAPACITY = 20;
  //...
private:
  int data[CAPACITY];
  size_t count;
  //...
}
```

the explanation said the second way is more "flexible".

This got me thinking what that "flexible" could mean.

So I've been thinking + searching Google and SO about it, and here's what I came up with:

1. since CAPACITY is a static constant, the compiler only declares it once so there's not a huge loss of memory in second method. + Even if I choose the first way of making a class, I would eventually create a public method that checks capacity (ex: `printCapacity()`) so I'm better off going with the second way.
2. It's easier to see how big the Bag class actually is just by looking at the code. (Although I don't think one would find it hard in the first one.)

I tried to find out why the second way would be more 'flexible' than the first one, but I couldn't get the answer that would get this 'flexible' word out of my head.

Maybe there is a programming convention about this?
Any more explanation would be really helpful + if there is anything wrong with what I came up with, it would also be really helpful to know.

Comment: The reason it's more flexible is that in the second method the capacity is specified in one place only, so if you want to change the capacity you only have to make one change to the code. In the first method the capacity is likely to be present in several places in the code and you will have to make sure to change all of them. If you get that wrong then you have a bug. So maybe 'flexible' isn't the precise word, 'maintainable' perhaps?

Comment: @john: Actually, `sizeof(Bag::Data)` will work everywhere.

Comment: On point 1, there's no loss of memory for declaring `CAPACITY` in this way. Don't think that just because you declare a variable in your code that the compiler *must* use some memory to store that variable. Compilers are perfectly capable of optimizing code and saving memory by not creating variables that aren't actually needed. I would expect that to happen in this case. In fact this is a good general principle, write clear straightforward code, and leave the micro-optimizations to the compiler.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me clear up my thoughts on my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown, it's not really more flexible. The benefit would come if you used `CAPACITY` for a second purpose, such as defining a the range of a loop. Then if you changed `CAPACITY` from, say, 20 to 30 you'd only need to make the change in one place.

That said, it would generally be much more flexible (at a very slight performance overhead) to use something like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the static constant?

1. To give the literal number more meaning. `CAPACITY` is not the same as `PARAMS_PER_PHASE * NUMBER_OF_PROJECT_PHASES` for example.
2. So that when you want to write code later on depending on that size, it can be `read_nums_from_file(my_file, Bag::CAPACITY)` rather than `read_nums_from_file(my_file, 20 )` or `read_nums_from_file(my_file, sizeof(Bag::data)/sizeof(int))`. The latter is not terrible, but still more cumbersome to read.

Comment: Watch out! `Bag::CAPACITY` is *not* the same as `sizeof(Bag::data)`. `CAPACITY` is the number of elements. `sizeof` gives the number of bytes, which is 4 * times as many (assuming a 4-byte `in`t).